# the difference of machine code between mov eax, 0 and mov ax, 0

Tags: nasm

I use nasm to study assembly. Below is the source code:

```
[BITS 32]
mov ebx, 0
mov bx, 0
mov bl, 0
```

then I use 'ndisasm -b 32 test.bin' to get output as following:

```
00000000  BB00000000        mov ebx,0x0
00000005  66BB0000          mov bx,0x0
00000009  B300              mov bl,0x0
```

My question is the difference of BB00000000 and 66BB0000, I know the opcode of MOV is B, but what is the 66 before B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x66 is operand-size override prefix which means that if the default operand size is 32-bit (as your case is), it becomes 16-bit a the opcode works on 16-bit size registers (bx in your case)

Comment: Oh thanks, can you give me some threads to get more information about operand-size?

Comment: @bobo This chart may help: http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#Operand-size_and_address-size_override_prefix